# Comments not being reliably ignored

Tags: regex, bash

I'm really puzzled. I've got nested loops reading in Hostnames and Commands from two separate files. In the files I want to put "#" commented lines, which need to be ignored by the main script. In the following script, the Commands are read fine, the "#" commented lines being ignored nicely, but the read of the Hostnames file gets the first hostname fine and then terminates the while/do loop!
If I actually put "#" commented lines in the Hostnames then it keeps reading them until it gets to a geniune hostname and then terminates the loop.

```
# Read the Hostname from Hostnames.txt
while read HOST
[[ "$HOST" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue  
do  
.  
  while read Cmd1 Cmd2 Cmd3 Prompt  
  # Read Commands from Commands1.txt file but ignore comment lines  
  [[ "$Cmd1" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue  
  do  
  .  
  .  
  done < Commands1.txt  
done < Hostnames.txt
```

Further weirdness: if I put a line `echo $HOST` following the `[[ "$HOST" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue` line it works as required but of course it's echoing an unwanted screen output.

Commands file content:

```
#Juniper commands  
set cli screen-length 0,show version,exit,>
```

Hostname file content

`ABCD1234`

Comment: I'm surprised it worked at all; don't you need `do` in a `while` loop? Did they make that optional?

Comment: Are the `#` characters in your input files *always* the first character on a line like your patterns require? Do you have DOS-style line endings (or worse yet, mixed line endings)? Maybe try something more like `while read ... done < <(grep -v '^#' input.txt)`...

Comment: Sorry @Tom Zych the 'do' statements were there just now shown.

Comment: Hi, @twalberg. The "#" characters are the first and the line endings are unix; cat -vet filename shows only what I expect, nothing else. 'cat -vet Hostnames.txt    # Test comment$    ABCD1234$    ABCD1235$    # ABCD1236$    ABCD1237$'

Comment: Looks like you have the `do` statements in the wrong place -- is this the way it is in the script?

Comment: Hi @Tom Zych  do statements in the wrong place ? Yes this is the way they are in the script. Where should they be please?

Comment: AHA!!! That works!!! I moved the "do" statements. Thank you very much all of you.

Comment: Guess someone should make it an answer, so it doesn't stay in the unanswered list. I will.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments, the `do` statements were in the wrong place; they should have come immediately after the `while` statements.

Comment: Thanks Tom, appreciated.